# am finding this error in my node express application its saying a function have named it sendMailer is not a function. this is when i trigger sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image: the error]

that is the error now
its saying that sendEmail function  is not a function
have done everything even changing the function format but its saying same error
have been doing this the whole day with any solution that have gotten
let me give the code of the function

```
 

async function sendEmail(emailOptions) {
 try{
 
   let emailTransporter = createTransporter();

    emailTransporter.sendMail(emailOptions);
 
 }catch(err){
   console.log(err)
 
 }
 
 };

module.exports = sendEmail
```

where am declaring the function..
am calling it in another file
where i add some parameters in the function
as seen in the code below

```
    const sendEmail = require('./nodemailer');


  async function sendConfirmationEmail (url, email) {
    try {
      const emailOptions = {
        from: `"  Perez Food Delivery" <${process.env.USER}> `,
        to: email,
        subject: "Comfirmation of account ",
        html: `
      <div style= "max-width:600px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;
      color: #5f6368;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
     ">welcome!</h1>
  
  
      <p style="
          margin: 0;
          font-size: 16px;
          ">
                
  
  
          </p>
       <div  style="width: fit-content;
  margin: 40px auto;
      " ><a href="${url}" target="_blank" style=" font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      color: #222;
      cursor:pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid #202124;
      background: #fcba1c;
      font-weight: 600;
      display: inline-block;">comfirm here</a></div>
  
             <p style="  margin-bottom:0;   font-size: 16px;">please click thebutton to navigate back to the site: </p>
  
        <p style="text-align:center; margin:10px 0;  font-size: 16px;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #FFA73B;">${url}</a></p>
  
    <p style="  font-size: 16px;">If this request is not made by you kindly ignore this mail..</p>
    <div>
        <p style="    font-size: 16px;
      padding: 30px 0;
      background: #ffd5a1;
          color: #5f6368;
      text-align: center;">with regards, Perez Food Delivery .</p>
  `,
      }
      
      await sendEmail(emailOptions);
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
 
  
  module.exports = sendConfirmationEmail;
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of export function is for arrow functions.

You should export function as follows:

```
module.exports = sendEmail();
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I executed the code and it did not give an error
Even your code did not give an error.
You can define a class and export the class and the function is in the class.

Comment: not yet working

Comment: update node.js version

Comment: To which version